# Meaning and examples of the word Silly

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can you share some feedback of the word **Silly**, **what Silly means**, expressions that you use in real life, the only thing that I know about this word it's like something dump or stupid, there's another meaning or usage of this word.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definitions of ***silly, dumb, stupid**?* What exactly do you find difficult to understand?

Comment: Related: Monty Python's [Ministry of Silly Walks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOqHNNmTz68) (for a use that is heavy on the "ridiculous" in the sense of "*ridiculously trivial or frivolous*")

Comment: @apsillers is awesome! That skit is amazing :D

Comment: It seems like there more to your question than could be answered by a dictionary, but in order to understand what you’re really asking we will need more context. Can you provide more of your thoughts on the matter, especially definitions you’ve found and what _you_ think the word means? _(see: [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please))_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly is an interesting word!

Silly can be used to express when something is lighthearted and not very serious. For example:

`My mother made silly faces at me when I was a baby to make me laugh.`

`Oh don't mind me, I'm just being silly right now!`

However, `silly` can also be used in a lightly insulting way and you should be careful using it to describe someone.

This is because silly basically means 'Not to be taken seriously'. So if there is a situation where it would be bad to called someone 'not someone to take seriously', then it can offend.

Examples of offensive/negative uses of silly:

`The meeting was useless and silly, we all know how to wash our hands!`

`She's just a silly woman, she can't be a CEO.`

Silly is not as harsh as 'stupid'.